# Can I use IF multiple times to switch between multiple options in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, scripting

hey i got 9 type on my web. i have to set different keywords each type. with this script;

```
if ($type = movie) {
$yazdir = "DVDRip, DVDScr";
}
elseif ($type = game) {
$yazdir = "Full Version, Patch";
}
```

i can write keywords for two type. how to repeat this correctly for other types? (echo paramether must be $yazdir)

Comment: Note that `=` is a assignment operator and not a comparison operation! The return value of an assignment operator is the new value that is being assigned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three options:

1. add more elseif
2. You can use `switch`

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

3.use associative arrays

```
$types = array( 
         "movies" => "DVDRip, DVDScr",
         "games" => "Full Version, Patch",
         ...
       );
```

Comment: im level 3/10 on php. can you give me some more information about using associative arrays?

Comment: Associative arrays are just arrays with text as keys instead of numbers.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php  So you can use $types['movies']  to get "DVDRip, DVDScr"

Comment: did you just copy paste the other 2 answers in your own? jesus! http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2274630/revisions

Answer (score 1):

Just keep adding `elseif`.

```
if ($type == "movie") {
$yazdir = "DVDRip, DVDScr";
} elseif ($type == "game") {
$yazdir = "Full Version, Patch";
} elseif ($type == "book") {
$yazdir = "Warez book";
}
```

Or you can use a switch, as Yada said.  Note that you must use break, or it will fall through.

Comment: thank you for your answer. to learn hard things, i will try to use associative arrays as Yada said. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself doing that many many times, then the problem at hand is best solved by an associative array which in your case will map $type keys to $yazdir values.